# Python Retain function. Use value from previous row in calculation

Tags: python, pandas, retain

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]:
     PART AVAILABLE_INVENTORY DEMAND
1    A    12                  6
2    A    12                  2
3    A    12                  1
4    B    24                  1
5    B    24                  1
6    B    24                  4
7    B    24                  3
```

Output wanted:

```
     PART AVAILABLE_INVENTORY DEMAND  AI   AI_AFTER
1    A    12                  6       12   6
2    A    12                  2       6    4
3    A    12                  1       4    3
4    B    24                  1       24   23
5    B    24                  1       23   22
6    B    24                  4       22   18
7    B    24                  3       18   15
```

The code I have so far is below but it is not giving the output I am looking for:

```
def retain(df):
    df['PREV_PART'] = df['PART'].shift()
    df['PREV_AI_AFTER'] = df['AI'].shift() - df['DEMAND'].shift()
    df['AI'] = np.where(df['PART'] != df['PREV_PART'], df['AI'], df['PREV_AI_AFTER'])
    df['AI_AFTER'] = df['AI'] - df['DEMAND']

df['AI'] = df['AVAILABLE_INVENTORY']
retain(df)
```

What is the fastest way to do this with performance in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with `groupby` with `cumsum` on the column 'DEMAND' and `shift` on the column 'AI_AFTER' just created before:

```
df['AI_AFTER'] = df['AVAILABLE_INVENTORY'] - df.groupby('PART')['DEMAND'].cumsum()
df['AI'] = df.groupby('PART')['AI_AFTER'].shift().fillna(df['AVAILABLE_INVENTORY'])
print (df)
  PART  AVAILABLE_INVENTORY  DEMAND  AI_AFTER    AI
1    A                   12       6         6  12.0
2    A                   12       2         4   6.0
3    A                   12       1         3   4.0
4    B                   24       1        23  24.0
5    B                   24       1        22  23.0
6    B                   24       4        18  22.0
7    B                   24       3        15  18.0
```

Answer (score 1):

VERRRY Similar to [Ben.T's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61348417/2336654).  Please choose their answer if you like this approach.  This is just how I'd arrange the process.

```
def f(d):
    i = d.AVAILABLE_INVENTORY
    c = d.DEMAND.cumsum()
    return pd.concat({'AI': i - c.shift(fill_value=0), 'AI_AFTER': i - c}, axis=1)

df.join(df.groupby('PART').apply(f))

  PART  AVAILABLE_INVENTORY  DEMAND  AI  AI_AFTER
1    A                   12       6  12         6
2    A                   12       2   6         4
3    A                   12       1   4         3
4    B                   24       1  24        23
5    B                   24       1  23        22
6    B                   24       4  22        18
7    B                   24       3  18        15
```